# Applying a transformation matrix in opengl

Tags: opengl

How can i apply a 4x4 rotation matrix using standard opengl commands? I have used rotation vectors before, but I cannot find how to apply a rotation matrix to an object?

Edit with more info:

I am trying to rotate a point in the origin using a direction vector as part of a physics simulator. I have been advised to use the up vector and the cross product to get a matrix:

{direction, up, cross, origin}

But I dont know how to apply this in openGL. Why is this depreciated?

Matrix that produces a 2D instead of 3D model:

```
Matrix44f rotation = Matrix44f(
    { crossproduct1[0], crossproduct1[1], crossproduct1[2], 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
    { directionvector[0], directionvector[1], directionvector[2], 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 1 });

    glMultMatrixf(rotation);
```

Comment: Do you have a rotation matrix already generated on the CPU? If so in deprecated OpenGL, you can use `glMultMatrixf (...)`. The matrix is expected to be stored as an array of 16 single-precision floats in column-major order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description (`{direction, up, cross, origin}`), what you are trying to describe is the ModelView matrix. *However, your X and Z axes appear to be transposed.*

#### The ModelView matrix is derived as such:

```
| Left_x  Up_x  Fwd_x  Eye_x |
| Left_y  Up_y  Fwd_y  Eye_y |
| Left_z  Up_z  Fwd_z  Eye_z |
|  0.0    0.0    0.0    1.0  |
```

It is actually the combination of a rotation (the top-left 3x3 matrix) 
***and*** translation matrix (the last column).

Generally the **X** (Left), **Y** (Up) and **Z** (Forward) axes are orthogonal so you can compute Left<sub>xyz</sub> as the cross product of Fwd and Up.

---

Regarding why `glMultMatrixf (...)` is deprecated, the OpenGL matrix stack was deemed deprecated in OpenGL 3.0 and removed beginning with OpenGL 3.1. This was done in order to eliminate fixed-function vertex processing and move to a shader-only API design.

In an OpenGL 3.0 or older context, OpenGL 3.1 with the `GL_ARB_compatbility` extension or a 3.2+ compatibility profile you can continue to use deprecated parts of the API. But in core OpenGL 3.1+ this part of the API no longer exists.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot. I got the above matrix to work for the rotation, however the model appears flat?

Comment: @user3319320: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Is there any chance you could link to or add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: I will try and find an example. The 3D object is only drawn in one axis as a completely 2D image... Looks like it has been run over with a car